# I understand the algorithm for k means.But don't understand on how to apply it on testing data

Tags: k-means

I am having problems not on understanding the  k means algorithm but on how to apply it on training ,validation and testing data.Is it like this:
Training phase: Apply k-means on the input data and then we get centroid value (in my case three).For each centroid value assign a label say 1,2,3.Suppose in training phase I input sixty such samples .So in total i get 60*3  centroids each with label 1,2,3..
Testing phase:Apply k means on the input signal.We get centroids.Compare this with centroid obtained from training phase centroids.Which ever is closest to it assign the same label for it?

Comment: Belongs on [stats.stackexchange.com](http://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

k-means does not have a "training" and a "testing" phase. It is an **unsupervised** algorithm.

At most, it is *only* applied to testing data.

Do not approach it like a classificator. It is not a classification algorithm.

The objective of k-means is:

> Split my input data set into `k` convex partitions, such that the sum of all squared deviations in all dimensions from the mean of each partition is smallest.

There are no labels.

Comment: Thank you so much.What will be the typical things I will be looking to make sure that k means algorithm is working properly?Also how should i calculate accuracy?

Comment: There is no such thing as accuracy in unsupervised learning. Because there are no true labels by definition. Analyze the result, learn from it. Maybe eventually decide it is good, and train a classifier to categorize new data the same way...